# How to make method return type as the current type in AspectJ ITD?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I need to introduce `save()` method to any type annotated with my `@Persistent` annotation. This method simply saves the object into the underlying database and returns a copy of the object back with its row id (e.g. `Person personSaved = person.save()`)

For this purpose, I wrote the given aspect using AspectJ (`PersistentObject` is an interface providing `save()` method):

```
public aspect PersistencyAspect {
    declare parents: (@Persistent *) implements PersistentObject;

    public PersistentObject PersistentObject.save() {
        // perform the save operation and return a copy of this
    }
}
```

The code above looks good. But my problem is the return type of `save()` method. I want to declare it as the actual type which is annotated by `@Persistent` (e.g. Person) instead of `PersistentObject`.

Do you have a solution for my issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you want. The technical answer is simply: no.

OTOH, I think this is not a big loss because what you want does not seem to be good application design anyway:

- You want `save()` to return an object which is kind of counterintuitive because it is not a getter. Why do you want to return an object you already have? I would expect `save()` to have a `void` return type.
- Is is not much cleaner and nicer to develop against interfaces than against specific classes? If you return anything, I guess the interface type is not such a bad choice.